# 10 second timeout on failing AAAA lookup before IPv4 fallback in file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, performance, dns, ipv6

PHP—or its subsystems—delays requests with 10 seconds attempting to get a AAAA lookup before falling back to IPv4 and succeeding. I have 15+ requests, so this problem results in 150 seconds+ spent just waiting for IPv6 lookups to fail. Neither the client nor remote hosts have IPv6 setup other than link-local.

```
file_get_contents( $ipv4_address); # works in less than a second
file_get_contents( $fqdn_address); # takes ten–eleven seconds
```

The only viable work-around I see is to use `gethostbyname( $fqdn_address );` to replace the hostname before sending it to `file_get_contents()`. I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

PS: This is on a shared host, so I have minimal control over the server configuration and setup.

Comment: This is likely a problem with your host’s DNS resolver. You should contact your host about it. Forcing IPv4 is a hack, and not solving the real problem.

Comment: I should have said: the DNS request for an AAAA instantly gets a response saying there is no response. This is repeated two times after five second intervals.

Comment: Do you have shell access to the machine? I would be interested to see the output of “time host $fqdn_address” and the like.

Comment: @jeremy-visser, `time host` returns the A record in real 0m0.101s, user 0m0.000s, sys 0m0.004s.

Comment: Hmm, on my system, “host” fetches both A and AAAA records if unspecified. You may need to run `time host -t aaaa`.

Comment: The title and the text does not match the responses you give in the comments. From what you said in the comments, there is NO delay in *lookups*. Hence my -1

Answer (score 1):

You could try using curl instead, which has the ability to force ipv4

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

Otherwise, it looks like serverside settings or php recompilations to fix, which you obviously aren't able to do on a shared platform.

Comment: I’d rather avoid curl if possible. There are other issues which I do not have with file_get_contents(), so I’d just replace one problem for another. I’m interested in seeing what can be done about this problem before investigating alternatives anyways.

Comment: Curl is brilliant, marvelous.  What issues do you have with Curl?